# How to return last page of webview to another view from a view

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a ios program for iPad. It is used 2 view, A view has webview, another has imageview. When I returned webview from imageview, webview is opened homepage. I want to return last page  . How can I do?

Comment: please explain the question furthermore, also post some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make sure, that the last page that was loaded in the UIWebView will be displayed again when you switch back to the UIWebView.

To achieve that you can keep track of the last URL that was loaded in the UIWebView. You can do that in the following UIWebViewDelegate method (declare `currentURL` as property):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
   self.currentURL = request.URL;
   return YES;
}
```

And then when you bring back your UIWebView:

```
- (void)showWebView {
  [yourWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:currentURL]];
}
```